# Button image not showing

Tags: python, django

I'm just learning how to use Django and HTML, and I encountered such a problem that my image is not displayed on the button, I don't understand what the error is and I will be grateful if someone can help me fix it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
   button {
    background-image: url("/main/static/main/img/i.jpg");
    padding-left: 32px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button></button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that your static url? You an see what it is in settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button>
    <img src=path />
</button>
```

would be easy solution? It depends how do you want it to be displayed. As button and inside a image or just image which can be clicked on?
Your image path must exists somewhere where it can pull it from.
EDIT: If you have Firefox Web Browser you can probably see in console (by pressing F12 on keyboard) what's the error message help you identify the source of the problem. I tried your code with another path to image and it works just the image is not centered vertically nor horizontally